# Create An Ajax Function To Update Records in Database using Yii Framework

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I've new to MVC and it's hurting my brain.

I've got a view as follows:

```
<div class="uk-width-1">
<!--<a href="--><?php //echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?><!--/admin/userList/Do/Add" class="uk-button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> --><?php //echo Yii::t("default","Add New")?><!--</a>-->
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/admin/driverList" class="uk-button"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <?php echo Yii::t("default","List")?></a>
</div>

<form id="frm_table_list" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="AdminDriverList">
<input type="hidden" name="tbl" id="tbl" value="drivers">
<input type="hidden" name="clear_tbl"  id="clear_tbl" value="clear_tbl">
<input type="hidden" name="whereid"  id="whereid" value="id">
<input type="hidden" name="slug" id="slug" value="driverList">
<table id="table_list" class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-striped uk-table-condensed">
  <!--<caption>Merchant List</caption>-->
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="3%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Driver ID")?></th>
            <th width="5%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Email")?></th>
            <th width="3%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Hourly Rate ($/hr)")?></th>
            <th width="3%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Minutes Worked")?></th>
            <th width="3%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Pay Owed ($)")?></th>
            <th width="3%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Amount Paid to Driver")?></th>
            <th width="3%"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Confirm Payment")?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Which successfully loads the correct data using:

```
    public function AdminDriverList()
    {

        $slug=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/admin/".$_GET['slug'];
        $stmt="SELECT * FROM
        {{drivers}}     
        ORDER BY id ASC                     
        ";
        if ($res=$this->rst($stmt)){
            foreach ($res as $val) {
                $action="<div class=\"options\">
                <a href=\"$slug/Do/Add/?id=$val[admin_id]\" >".Yii::t("default","Edit")."</a>
                <a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"row_del\" rev=\"$val[admin_id]\" >".Yii::t("default","Delete")."</a>
                </div>";
                /*$date=Yii::app()->functions->prettyDate($val['date_created']);
                $date=Yii::app()->functions->translateDate($date);     */
                $feed_data['aaData'][]=array(
                    $val['id'],
                    $val['email'],
                    $val['hourly_rate'],
                    $val['minutes_worked'],
                    round($val['hourly_rate'] * $val["minutes_worked"] / 60, 2),
                    "<input type=\"number\" name=\"amount_paid_to_driver\" placeholder=\"Enter amount paid\" step=\"0.01\"/>",
                    "<button id='confirm_driver_payment'>Confirm Payment</button>"
                );
            }
            $this->otableOutput($feed_data);
        }
        $this->otableNodata();
    }
```

But I'm struggling to add another action to the Confirm Payment button.

But I am unsure how I Confirm Payment button that will successful take the amount from the amount_paid_to_driver field and minus it from the SQL database known as mt_drivers at the correct driver ID.

Any guidance for a newb appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a detail of `$('#confirm_driver_payment').click()` function ?

Comment: I'm so stupid, my SQL function was incorrect. Was passed incorrect secret_id from another part of my system.